# Solving differential equations on c++

Tags: c++, c++11

The **main** function runs a loop that feeds vector values to a serie of sequentially interdependent differential equations found in another function **gate_probabilities**, which feeds back the calculations to main and the loop repeats.

The solutions for the equations are serially fed each into its corresponding vector, this takes place in both functions. intermediate equations are **m_new; h_new; n_new**,  the main vector to eventually be plotted against time is **V**. (plotting not in the code)

The vectors are defined outside the function body (they are thought of as global but i guess the issue is they're not properly declared as such)

Building produces no errors, but i do get a debug error on execution: "Abort() has been called".

would appreciate any help :)

```
#include "C:\Users\jenbe\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\std_lib_facilities.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<double> mvector;
vector<double> hvector;
vector<double> nvector;
vector<double> V; // potential vector
vector<double> timevector;

//global constants

double gL = 0.1; // mS/cm^2
double gK = 9;
double gNa = 35;
double EL = -65; // mV
double EK = -90;
double ENa = 55;
double phi = 5; // Coefficient increasing reaction speed of the alpha and beta constants which it multiplies.
double Iapp = 5; // microAmpere values (as in Wang-Buzsaki)
double runtime = 3000;// 3 Seconds
double dt = 0.001; // Timestep = 1ms
double V_init = -60;


std::tuple<double> gate_probabilities(double v, double m, double h, double n) { 
    double am, bm, ah, bh, an, bn, dh, dn;

    //first stage -> gate probabilities

    am = -0.1*(v + 35) / (exp(-0.1*(v + 35)) - 1); //the probability of a closed gate to open
    bm = 4 * exp(-(v + 60) / 18); //the probability of an open gate to be closed.
    ah = 0.07*exp(-(v + 58) / 20);
    bh = 1 / (exp(-0.1*(v + 28)) + 1);
    an = -0.01*(v + 34) / (exp(-0.1*(v + 34)) - 1);
    bn = 0.125 * exp(-(v + 44) / 80);

    //second stage -> gate states

    dh = phi * ( ah*(1 - h) - bh*h); // inactivation variable h
    dn = phi * ( an*(1 - n) - bn*n); // inward recitifier

    double m_new = am / (am + bm);   //activation variable 
    double h_new = dh*dt + h;
    double n_new = dn*dt + n;

    mvector.push_back(m_new);
    hvector.push_back(h_new); 
    nvector.push_back(n_new);

    // third stage -> currents

    double IL = gL*(v - EL);
    double INa = gNa * pow(m, 3) * h * (v - ENa);
    double IK = gK * pow(n, 4) * (v - EK); // delayed recitifier
    double currents = -INa - IK - IL + Iapp;

    return std::make_tuple(currents);
}


int main() {

             //initialize vectors - later modify with function within function
    double ami = -0.1*(V_init + 35) / (exp(-0.1*(V_init + 35)) - 1);
    double bmi = 4 * exp(-(V_init + 60) / 18);
    double ahi = 0.07*exp(-(V_init + 58) / 20); // 
    double bhi = 1 / (exp(-0.1*(V_init + 28)) + 1);
    double ani = -0.01*(V_init + 34) / (exp(-0.1*(V_init + 34)) - 1);
    double bni = 0.125 * exp(-(V_init + 44) / 80);
    V.push_back(V_init); //V_init
    double m_init = (ami / (ami + bmi));
    double h_init = (ahi / (ahi + bhi)); 
    double n_init = (ani / (ani + bni));

    mvector.push_back(m_init); 
    hvector.push_back(h_init);
    nvector.push_back(n_init);

    for (int i{ 1 }; i <= runtime; ++i) { // 1ms iterations over 3000ms range

        auto ret = gate_probabilities(V[i - 1], mvector[i - 1], hvector[i - 1], nvector[i - 1]);
        double currents;
        currents = std::get<0>(ret);

        double potential = currents*dt + V[i - 1]; //calculate new V.
        V.push_back(potential); //incorporates new V into a vector.
        timevector.push_back( timevector[i - 1] + dt );
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know which line cause `abort` to fire?  If not you should use your debugger to find it.

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x7407B832 in Source1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Range_error at memory location 0x00AFFB9C.

Comment: line 1234 vector subscript out of range

Comment: In your loop `for (int i{ 1 }; i <= runtime; ++i)` you need to make sure `i` is less then the size of the vectors you accessing with it.

Comment: thank you so much Nathan, the problem was indeed a misalignment between the iteration and vector size :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line

```
timevector.push_back( timevector[i - 1] + dt );
```

will not work on the very first loop run, as timevector is empty.

Comment: thank you clever and sharp mister Jodocus ;) lifesaver